# Erro Firestore react native

Tags: firebase, react-native, front-end, react-hooks, firestore

Estou tentando pegar as informações da minha coleção no firebase mais estou recebendo o seguinte erro:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating
> '_firebaseConnection.default.db.collection')

esse é meu código do firebase

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/database';

let firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  databaseURL: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: "",
  measurementId: ""

};

if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
}

const db = firebase.firestore();



export {db}

export default firebase;
```

o firestore só aparece quando eu coloco:

```
 const db = firebase.firestore();
  export default {
      firebase,
     db
 };
```

desse formato acima eu não consigo sair do aplicativo da erro de auth

Código da minha tela de livro aonde o erro ocorre:

```
   import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import {
    StatusBar,
    FlatList, View
} from "react-native";
import * as OpenAnything from "react-native-openanything";

import {
    Container,
    InpuText,
    ViewFlatlist,
    Image,
    TextOne,
    ButtomSimple,
    TextButtom,
    ContainerRow,
    ContainerInput,
} from "./styles";
import { Card } from "react-native-elements";
import firebase from '../../services/firebaseConnection';

export default function Libery() {
    const [Libery, setLibery] = useState([]);


    useEffect(() => {
        firebase.db.collection("biblioteca").onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
            const Libery = [];
            querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
                const { title, category, uri, pdf } = doc.data();
                Libery.push({
                    id: doc.id,
                    title,
                    category,
                    uri,
                    pdf
                });
            });
            console.log(Libery)
            setLibery(Libery);
        });
    }, []);
```

Comment: Como está o import no componente?

Comment: `import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";  import { StatusBar, FlatList, View } from "react-native"; import * as OpenAnything from "react-native-openanything"; import { Container, InpuText, ViewFlatlist, Image, TextOne, ButtomSimple, TextButtom, ContainerRow, ContainerInput, } from "./styles"; import { Card } from "react-native-elements"; import firebase from '../../services/firebaseConnection'; export default function Libery() { const [Libery, setLibery] = useState([]);`

Answer (score -1):

Resolvido.

Eu só precisava chamar o firestone dentro a screens  de livros

Dessa forma:

import 'firebase/firestore';

const db = firebase.firestore();

db.collection("biblioteca").....